# Changing UILabel with a button

Tags: uiviewcontroller, delegates, popover

So, I have this popover who can be activated by four viewcontrollers.
Inside this popover, I click on a button and this button changes one UILabel which is in the viewcontroller which activated the popover.

But, the problem is: depending on which viewcontroller actives the popover, the text is different.

My question: how can I set one if clause to know from which viewcontroller activated the popover?

Here is the code that changes the UILabel, where I have to implement the if clause:

```
- (void) escolheu1:(id)sender {
    [delegate menuController:self 
         hasPressedSomething:
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"They are panels composed by odd numbers of layers, which are crossed with each other in order to obtain more strength."]];
}
```

I guess I gotta use isKindOfClass method, maybe not, I don't know.

Can you guys help, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a "`sender`" parameter being sent to your "`escolheu1:`" method (and while we're on the subject, you should declare it as an "`(IBAction)`" and not a "`(void)`").

And with that sender parameter, you can determine which button (in each of the four view controllers) sent you that message.

One way to do this is via setting a "`tag`" value for the buttons in each of the view controllers in your storyboard, and then you can easily determine which button called this method like this:

```
- (IBAction) escolheu1:(id)sender {
   UIButton * theButton = (UIButton *) sender;
   NSLog( @"which button has this tag? --> %d", theButton.tag );
   ....
   ....
   ....
}
```

Comment: Actually it's the same button for all the 4 viewcontrollers (the buttons are inside the popover, so they are the same), so I think a tag would not work, am I right?

Comment: you can also programmatically (via code) set the tag when you bring up your popover (e.g. expose your button via a "`@property`" and then set it via something like "`myPopover.button.tag = 2;` for view controller #2).

Comment: Would I have to create a delegate to set the tags? (the popover is in different class).